# NumPy error saying that matrices are not aligned

Tags: python, numpy

If I run:

```
x = np.zeros(6)
y = np.zeros([7, 6])
z = y * x
```

Then everything is fine, and there are no Python errors.

However, I am using a Python module (call if foo) containing a function (call if bar), which returns a 7x6 NumPy array. It has the same shape as `y` above, and the same data type (float64). But when I run the following:

```
x = np.zeros(6)
y = foo.bar()
z = y * x
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: shapes (7,6) and (1,6) not aligned: 6 (dim 1) != 1 (dim 0)
```

But as far as I can tell, `y` is exactly the same format in these two examples, with the same shape and data type. What's causing this error, and why is it not caused in the first example?

Comment: The `foo.bar` array is `np.matrix`,  Its * is matrix product, np.dot.

Comment: In your first example x.shape is `(6,)`. In the second one the shape is `(1, 6)`. Your code snippet does not correspond tow hat you are doing. Double check your code and make sure what you post is what is happening. The error is pretty self-explanatory. The dimensions of the arrays need to agree for matrix multiplication `(m, n) * (n, p)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [446]: x = np.zeros(6) 
     ...: y = np.zeros([7, 6]) 
     ...: z = y * x                                                                                    
In [447]: z.shape                                                                                      
Out[447]: (7, 6)
```

Here we are doing element-wise multiplication, a (7,6) with a (6,).  By broadcasting the (6,) becomes (1,6) and then (7,6) to match `y`.

Evidently in the `foo.bar` case, `y` is `np.matrix` subclass:

```
In [454]: y1 = np.matrix(y)                                                                            
In [455]: y1*x                                                                                         
---...
    219             # This promotes 1-D vectors to row vectors
--> 220             return N.dot(self, asmatrix(other))
...
ValueError: shapes (7,6) and (1,6) not aligned: 6 (dim 1) != 1 (dim 0)
```

Note the different display for `y1`:

```
In [456]: y1                                                                                           
Out[456]: 
matrix([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

With `np.matrix` `*` is defined as `np.dot`, the matrix product.  The `x` is also converted `np.matrix`, producing a (1,6) matrix.  The error message follows from the definition of matrix multiplication.

`np.multiply` can be used force the element-wise multiplication.  Note the class of the result:

```
In [458]: np.multiply(y1,x)                                                                            
Out[458]: 
matrix([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

Because of confusions like this `np.matrix` is being discouraged.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which version you're running, but I am running version 1.16.3 on Python 3.

It seems to me you're defining your `x` differently than in your example snippet. You seem to be defining it as a 6x1 matrix instead of a "vector", which is considered on Numpy to only have one dimension. Try multiplying `y` by `np.zeros([6,1])` and you'll see an error.

Bottom line is:

1. Use the `.shape` property a lot when debugging, it's very useful when you're doing matrix multiplication.
2. On np, multiplication between a matrix and a one dimensional array is carried differently than multiplications between 2 matrices.

Comment: I don't see a 0d array in this question

Comment: What I mean is that if you see the shape of np.zeros(6) with np.zeros(6).shape it is of dimension (6,). But you are correct, this is not a 0d array. Gonna edit it.